# how can i fetch all age less than 30 in this object using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var staff = [
    {name:"abiodun_adegbuyi",age:40,gender:"male",position:"head_developer",phone_number:0001},
    {name:"ajayi_seun ",age:35,gender:"female",position:"head_developer2",phone_number:0002},
    {name:"olayiwola_{samiat",age:22,gender:"female",position:"developer",phone_number:0003},
    {name:"rookie",age:22,gender:"male",position:"developer",phone_number:0004},
    {name:"wale",age:30,gender:"male",position:"tester",phone_number:0005},
    {name:"elizabeth",age:28,gender:"female",position:"acccountant",phone_number:0006},
    {name:"ijeoma",age:40,gender:"female",position:"receptionist",phone_number:0007},
    {name:"victoria",age:25,gender:"female",position:"head_developer",phone_number:0008},
    {name:"dr_femi",age:40,gender:"male",position:"managing_director",phone_number:0009},
    {name:"Mr_taiwo",age:40,gender:"male",position:"head_accountant",phone_number:0010},
];
```

Comment: Add the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

`var filteredArray = staff.filter(function(item){ return item.age < 30 });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is you meant fetch or rather filter

What about this?

```
staff.filter(member => member.age < 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array#filter method.  this will return a new array with the filtered values.  Here is an example.

```
const filtered = staff.filter(person => person.age < 30).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it may help u.

```
var staff=[ {name:"abiodun_adegbuyi",age:40,gender:"male",position:"head_developer",phone_number:0001}, {name:"ajayi_seun ",age:35,gender:"female",position:"head_developer2",phone_number:0002}, {name:"olayiwola_{samiat",age:22,gender:"female",position:"developer",phone_number:0003}, {name:"rookie",age:22,gender:"male",position:"developer",phone_number:0004}, {name:"wale",age:30,gender:"male",position:"tester",phone_number:0005}, {name:"elizabeth",age:28,gender:"female",position:"acccountant",phone_number:0006}, {name:"ijeoma",age:40,gender:"female",position:"receptionist",phone_number:0007}, {name:"victoria",age:25,gender:"female",position:"head_developer",phone_number:0008}, {name:"dr_femi",age:40,gender:"male",position:"managing_director",phone_number:0009}, {name:"Mr_taiwo",age:40,gender:"male",position:"head_accountant",phone_number:0010}];

var resultArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<staff.length; i++) {
  if(staff[i].age < 30) {
    resultArray.push(staff[i]);
  }
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over all object and compare values :

```
for (var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
    if (staff[i].age > 30) {

      //your code
    }
```